# How to free up space on non-responsive full btrfs system?

Tags: btrfs

I copied files to a btrfs raid-1, which turned out not to fit.

When the drives became full, they also became unresponsive.

`ls [directory]`, never finishes.

I tried `rm [raid-mount]/[file-i-know-exists]` hoping to free up space, but that also never comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `btrfs fi balance` command.

Your question doesn't provide enough info for a detailed answer. Try this wiki page for info on the balance command:

https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#I_get_.22No_space_left_on_device.22_errors.2C_but_df_says_I.27ve_got_lots_of_space